# FileSystemWatcher DCOM Errors

Tags: c#, iis, service, filesystemwatcher, dcom

Most would probably ignore this but I really need help. I am currently developing a Windows Service that uses FileSystemWatcher to monitor the changes on the web.config files on remote web servers.

What it generally does is upon initialization of the service, it gets the websites on IIS from a list of web servers defined in app.config, then puts a FileSystemWatcher on the the websites' web.config file and another file named web.config.orig.

When either the web.config or the web.config.orig file changes, it triggers the FileSystemWatcher then checks the LastModifiedDate of both files. If is not equal, it should generate an event log that says the the file's modified dates are not in sync.

The service successfully installs then I was able to test it one time, but it triggers the FileSystemWatcher a lot then generates a lot of this sort of error in the System Logs:

DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer Server1 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     4c08 (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\DynamicFSW\DynamicFSW\bin\Debug\DynamicFSW.exe).

You can download the source code here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pkh543g5n578fy/DynamicFSW.rar?dl=0

```
private void file_OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = (FileSystemWatcher)sender;

        try
        {                
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
            string webconfig = directory + "\\web.config";
            string webconfigorig = directory + "\\web.config.orig";

            DateTime dt1 = File.GetLastWriteTime(webconfig);
            DateTime dt2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(webconfigorig);

            DynamicFSWEventLog.WriteEntry("" + e.FullPath);

            string server = "";
            for (int i = 2; i < directory.Length; i++)
            {
                if (directory[i] != '\\')
                {
                    server += directory[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            DynamicFSWEventLog.WriteEntry("" + server);

            if (!System.DateTime.Equals(dt1, dt2))
            {
                ServerManager IIS = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(server);
                foreach (Site site in IIS.Sites)
                {
                    if (Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath).Equals("\\\\" + server + "\\" + site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath.Replace(':', '$')))
                    {
                        string message = "Server: " + server + "\n" +
                                         "Website: " + site.Name + "\n" +
                                         "Web.config.LastWriteTime: " + dt1 + "\n" +
                                         "Web.config.orig.LastWriteTime: " + dt2 + "\n\n" +
                                         "Web.config and Web.config.orig file's last write time not in sync!";

                        DynamicFSWEventLog.WriteEntry("" + message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }


    }
```

I would really appreciate anyone's help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I didnt think the filewatcher was good at watching something elses drives..  what user account are you using - and sadly I cant download your code - please do a minimum viable reproduction code and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've edited the question with the file_OnChanged code. Thanks!